# How to print out every input?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm suppose to write a code using arrays and inputs then split the list from people above 16 and people below 16. but can't seem to get the code to print every input. it only wants to print the last input I did. Here is what I have so far:

```
A = [0 for x in range (10)]
B = [0 for x in range (10)]

for i in range (10):
    A[i] = input('enter A name: ')
    B[i] = input('enter the age to go with the name: ')
    print()
    B2 = int(B[i])

if B2 > 16:
    print(B2, A[i])

if B2 < 16:
    print(A[2], B2)
```

Comment: do you want to print on each input? why did you out-dent the conditions?

Comment: put the two `if` blocks inside the `for` loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because, you are overwriting `B2` in the line `B2 = int(B[i])` at every single iteration of `i` inside the for loop ( `for i in range (10):` ) The following code should work:

```
A , B = [], []

for i in range(10):
    A += [raw_input('enter A name: ')]
    B += [input('enter the age to go with the name: ')]
    print()    

for i in range(len(B)):    
    if B[i] >= 16: print(B[i], A[i])        

    if B[i] < 16: print(A[i], B[i])
```

In the above code `A` is a list which stores all the names as strings. `B` is another list which stores all ages as `int` data types.

```
print A
>>>['Name1', 'Name2', 'Name3', 'Name4', 'Name5', 'Name6', 'Name7', 'Name8', 'Name9', 'Name10']       

print B
>>>[18, 10, 19, 5, 55, 12, 6, 66, 14, 7]
```

Comment: @PatrickArtner : I was not sure if the `A[2]` was added for some debugging. So, in my initial post, I didn't change it. I have changed it now, in the hope that it was indeed a typing error. Flipping A and B around may again be some debugging (I am not sure.) So, I didn't change that.

Comment: @PatrickArtner : I don't know if TheNuggetOf Gaming will prefer `if B[i] >= 16:` over `if B[i] <= 16:` . Or, if 16 year olds are intentionally left alone in the code. I did the basic minimum to identify the problem in the code, and left the philosophy of the code intact. However, I have edited the post to include `if B[i] >= 16:` following your comment.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are overwriting `B2` since the if condition is outside the for loop. Every time `B2` will get overwritten by what input user provides. I don't know what you are trying to do with the printing part . but putting it in loop should fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your code does ignore 16y olds and has some other problems.

You can either filter the input directly after input into two seperate lists (`under_16`,`over_15`) or simply throw all into one list (`all_studs`) and filter them later using [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) or [filter-function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) :

```
under_16 = []  # immediatly sorted
over_15 = []   # immediatly sorted
all_studs =[]  # all of them

for i in range (10):
    name = input('enter A name: ')
    while True:
        # avoid input of "ten" when age is asked - ask until valid
        try:
            age = int(input('enter the age to go with the name: '))  
            break
        except Exception: 
            print("Try again - input age. Hint: a _number_")

    # add all to big list
    all_studs.append((name,age))

    # sort immediately on input
    if age < 16:
        under_16.append( (name,age))
    else:
        over_15.append( (name,age))

# get from list by list-comp: 
under = [ (name,age) for name,age in all_studs if age < 16 ]
over =  [ (name,age) for name,age in all_studs if age >= 16 ]

# get from list by filter:
un = list(filter(lambda x:x[1]<16,all_studs))
ov = list(filter(lambda x:x[1]>15,all_studs))

print(un)        
print(ov)       

print(under)     
print(over)      

print(under_16)  
print(over_15)   

print(all_studs)
```

Output (for input `Phil,2,A,19,B,18,C,17,D,16,E,15,F,14,G,13,H,12,I,11,J,10`):

```
# un, under, under_16
[('Phil', 2), ('E', 15), ('F', 14), ('G', 13), ('H', 12), ('I', 11)]

# ov, over, over_15
[('A', 19), ('B', 18), ('C', 17), ('D', 16)]

# all_studs 
[('Phil', 2), ('A', 19), ('B', 18), ('C', 17), ('D', 16), ('E', 15), 
 ('F', 14), ('G', 13), ('H', 12), ('I', 11)]
```